# Greater than returns wrong value on numbers lower then 100

Tags: javascript

This is my first JavaScript project, so I'm sure this code isn't pretty, and could be written in a much better way, but that aside, I've encountered a problem I just don't understand. I'm sure it's just a bug I've made myself, but I just simply can't find it.

The '>' (greater than) operator works fine on numbers over 100, but stops working when it gets to 100. For some reason 100 > 99 returns false?

https://jsbin.com/vigocu/edit?console,output

Move the slider to the right, and then slowly to the left, and you will see it returning "true" until it reaches 100. From there it returns "false"

```
function getSliderInput(inputSliderId) {
  var backSwingArray = [100];
  var downSwingArray = [];


  document.querySelector('#' + inputSliderId).addEventListener('input', fillArray , false);

function fillArray() {

  if (isNaN(downSwingArray[downSwingArray.length - 1]) && backSwingArray[backSwingArray.length - 1] < this.value) {
    backSwingArray.push(this.value);
  } else if (downSwingArray[downSwingArray.length - 1] > this.value || isNaN(downSwingArray[downSwingArray.length - 1])){
    console.log('Is ' + downSwingArray[downSwingArray.length - 1] + ' > ' + this.value + ' return ' + (downSwingArray[downSwingArray.length - 1] > this.value));
    downSwingArray.push(this.value);
  } else {
    console.log('Is ' + downSwingArray[downSwingArray.length - 1] + ' > ' + this.value + ' return ' + (downSwingArray[downSwingArray.length - 1] > this.value));
    return;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You sure the values you're comparing are both Numbers? This could be a type mismatch problem -- comparing a string to a number. Try wrapping both values in a Number() function and see if the response changes.

Comment: Your JSBin fails with `"ReferenceError: getSliderInput is not defined at onload (https://null.jsbin.com/runner:1:162) at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.3.min.js:1:13627 at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.3.min.js:1:10537"` In any case, wherever possible live examples should be here, on-site, using Stack Snippes (the `<>` button).

Comment: Instead of `this.value`, use `parseInt(this.value, 10)` to make sure the value string gets converted to a number!

Comment: Is the JSBin not working for any of you?

I've tested it in several browsers and it works fine here.

Comment: @HenrikMadsen: Not for me on Chrome 46.0.2490.80 on Linux (see above).

Comment: They are strings before comparing them. I thought javascript did type conversion, so I didn't think that would be a problem?

But then again it works perfectly until it gets to 100.

Comment: @HenrikMadsen: See my answer for why you're ending up with a string comparison. (Particularly the last sentence...maybe I should make it the first sentence.) (Yes. Not the first, but much higher up.)

Comment: Problem solved and understood so I don't make that mistake again :-)
Thank you guys

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`value` on `input` elements is always a *string*. While that won't be a problem initially, when you're comparing `this.value` to the `100` you've put in the array to start with, you then push `this.value` into the array as-is (as a string). That means later, you'll end up comparing that stored string with another `this.value` value, which is also a string. If either operand to `>` is a number, it will coerce the other operand to number (the way `+` does, see below), but if **both** operands are strings, it will do a lexical comparison, not a numeric one, and `"100"` is indeed `<` `"99"` because `"1"` is `<` `"9"`.

So you want to convert `this.value` to a number early on, and then use that number both when comparing and when pushing into your array. You have many ways to do that:

- The unary `+` will require the entire string to be a valid number, but will treat `""` as `0`; it will also treat strings starting with `0x` as hexadecimal

  ```
  var num = +this.value;
  // or perhaps
  var num = this.value === "" ? NaN : +this.value;
  // or even
  var str = this.value.trim(); // .trim can be shimmed on obsolete browsers
  var num = str === "" ? NaN : +str;
  ```
- `parseInt(..., 10)` (the 10 is specifying the radix [number base] to use) will allow garbage at the end of the string, treat `""` as `NaN`, and treat any string prefixed with `0x` as `0` (since it stops at the first invalid character)

  ```
  var num = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  ```
- `Number(...)` does what `+` does

  ```
  var num = Number(this.value); // or variations above on +
  ```